# How to insert MAX (text) as WHERE clause?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I should be searching based on two WHERE clauses at the same time. One is a simple clause, the other is MAX (text). How to solve?

```
x = cursor.execute('SELECT product FROM electronics WHERE brand = ? AND MAX(price)' [combo_brand])
```

`Price` is a column of a database. I want to take the highest value of the column records. I would like to select the product with the maximum price, and search by it and by brand at the same time.

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `MAX(price)` is not a valid predicate. What do you want to express with it?

Comment: Which database are you using? `MySQL` and `SQLite` are mutually exclusive; you can't be using both at the same time. Please update the tags to reflect the correct database.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, which will help explain what your query is trying to do.

Comment: @TheImpaler price is a column of a database. i want to take the highest value of the column records

Comment: @ObsidianAge SQLite. Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the product having the max price for a given brand, then use:

```py
sql = '''SELECT product
FROM electronics
WHERE brand = ? AND price = (SELECT MAX(e.price)
                             FROM electronics e
                             WHERE e.brand = electronics.brand)'''
x = cursor.execute(sql, (combo_brand,))
records = cursor.fetchall()
print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
for row in records:
    print(row)
```

If instead you want the product with the maximum price across all brands, then use:

```py
sql = '''SELECT product
FROM electronics
WHERE brand = ? AND price = (SELECT MAX(price) FROM electronics)'''
x = cursor.execute(sql, (combo_brand,))
```

But I suspect the first version is what you want.

Comment: What does "e" and "e22 mean? Why are they used? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, `e2.price` was a typo and it has been fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'll try and I'll let you know. give me some minutes

Comment: Yes, the first version is what I would like. But there is a problem. When i print what the sql code selects, I get "None"

Comment: @Bobby I have added code showing how you may iterate through the result set.

Comment: All ok. I set your answer as a solution